# ParameterSet as an option

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

The objective is followed (for parameterset). I am new for parameterset concept, and I could not figure it out.

- switch `$opt1` and switch `$opt2` selected TOGETHER, NOT OK!
- switch `$opt1` selected, OK!
- switch `$opt2` selected, OK!
- No switch selected, OK!

```bsh
function Mytest {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$intro="ParameterSet Practice",
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='option1')][switch]$opt1,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName='option2')][switch]$opt2
    )

    Write-Verbose "$intro" -Verbose
    if ($opt1) {
        "You picked option 1!"
    } elseif ($opt2) {
        "You picked option 2!"
    } else {
        "You didn't pick an option!"
    }
}
```

The first 3 scenarios all worked except the last one. Please help me where did I made mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only after I posted my question, I figured it out. I didn't know I have to set the defaultparameter, Solution as follow:

```
function Mytest {
    param(
        [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="noOption")]
        ...
}
```

After the line above added into the codes. the fourth condition "No switch selected, OK!" is satisfied.

Comment: Any other alternative solution?

Comment: That's how you do it.